# Calling a method after *ngIf - Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

I would like to call a method every time that one of my templates appear

```
<div *ngIf="test" class="col-md-8">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option type="text>{{test}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

is it possible to execute a method when`test` contains a value and run the `*ngIf`?

Comment: Do that from your controller for component, i.e. typescript/javascript. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? What do you mean 'every time one of your templates appear'? Also, what do you mean by run the *ngIf?

Comment: I am showing this template when I get a value for test. I would like to display this template plus calling a method

Comment: Don't rely on your template to "call a method". Templates are used to display UI and user interaction, that is the extent of it. To figure out what it is you actually need you have to explain what it is you want to occur because "call a method" is too broad.

Comment: I guess it must be like (click) or (change).

Answer (score 2):

You're approaching it the wrong way. Do not call methods because something happens in DOM -- that goes against the pattern that Angular is trying to enforce.

Your model (from the .ts file) should control the template, not the other way around. Instead of thinking "call this method when a part of template disappears", go a step back and ask yourself:

> What is causing the `*ngIf` to toggle component?

There's your answer. For example, say you have something like the following.

```
toggle() {
  this.flag = !this.flag
}
```

That's the place where your model changes. If you want something else to happen when the flag is switched, do it there.

```
toggle() {
  doSomething()
  this.flag = !this.flag
}
```

If you want it to happen only when the flag is raised (becomes true), just use a conditional statement.

```
toggle() {
  if (!this.flag) {
    doSomething() // only when turning from false to true
  }
  this.flag = !this.flag
}
```